# How to fix Heap Corruption after dynamically struct allocation?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, heap-memory

I am trying to dynamically allocate a matrix as a continuous memory block

```
typedef struct 
{
    uint32_t m_width_u32;
    uint32_t m_height_u32;
    uint16_t *m_pixels_u16;
}IMG_t;

IMG_t* img = (IMG_t*)malloc(sizeof(IMG_t));

strcpy(lv_path_to_input_image, argv[1]); 
FILE* file = fopen(file_name, "r");

fscanf(file, "%d%d", &(img->m_height_u32), &(img->m_width_u32)

img->m_pixels_u16 = malloc( sizeof(*img->m_pixels_u16) * img->m_height_u32 * img->m_width_u32);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < img->m_height_u32; ++i)
{
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < img->m_width_u32; ++j)
    {
        fscanf(file, "%d", img->m_pixels_u16 + img->m_height_u32 * i + j);
    }
}
fclose(file);

if (img->m_pixels_u16 != NULL)
{
    free(img->m_pixels_u16);
}
free(img);
```

With this allocation I got a `HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED` error, meaning that I use more memory than I allocate.

However, if I extend the allocated memory only with 2 bytes more, heap corruption error is no longer present.

```
img->m_pixels_u16 = malloc( sizeof(*img->m_pixels_u16) * img->m_height_u32 * img->m_width_u32 +2 );
```

Can you please help me to understand this behavior?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Have you looked at the code that accesses `m_pixels_u16` to check for an out of bounds or off-by-one indexing error? Maybe it's not a coincidence that `sizeof(uint16_t)` is 2 and your +2 "fix" makes the error go away...

Comment: I assume that `img->m_height_u32` and `img->m_width_u32` are properly initialized?

Comment: I updated the question with minimal implementation witch reproduce the behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 32-bit `int` systems, wrong specifier leads to UB.

OP's code is saving to a 4-byte location when it should be 2 byte.  This may have benign consequences until the last array element which writes outside the bounds and *nicely* triggers `HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED`.  A +2 allocation hides the issue.

Use matching specifiers and enabled all warnings.  A good compiler, well enabled, would have warned about specifier/argument mismatch and saved time.

Also see [@Ôrel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62563168/2410359) about wrong index calculation

```
uint16_t *m_pixels_u16;
...
//fscanf(file, "%d", img->m_pixels_u16 + img->m_height_u32 * i + j);
fscanf(file, "%" SCNu16, img->m_pixels_u16 + img->m_width_u32 * i + j);
//            ^^^^^^^^^                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Same issue with (but OP might get "lucky" here)

```
//fscanf(file, "%d%d", &(img->m_height_u32), &(img->m_width_u32)
fscanf(file, "%" SCNu32 "%" SCNu32, &(img->m_height_u32), &(img->m_width_u32)
```

---

Other issues

`sizeof(*img->m_pixels_u16) * img->m_height_u32 * img->m_width_u32` may quietly overflow.  The below offers overflow detection.

```
unsigned long long n = 1ULL * img->m_height_u32 * img->m_width_u32;
assert(n <= SIZE_MAX/sizeof(*img->m_pixels_u16)); 
n *= sizeof(*img->m_pixels_u16);
```

---

BTW: good use of `p = malloc(sizeof *p * ...)` with

```
img->m_pixels_u16 = malloc( sizeof(*img->m_pixels_u16) * img->m_height_u32 * img->m_width_u32);
```

Recommend using that here too.

```
// IMG_t* img = (IMG_t*)malloc(sizeof(IMG_t));
IMG_t* img = malloc(sizeof *img);
```

---

Test not needed.  `free(NULL)` is OK.

```
//if (img->m_pixels_u16 != NULL)
//{
    free(img->m_pixels_u16);
//}
```

Yet `NULL` test would have been useful right after the `malloc()`.  Note image size *could* legitimately be zero.

```
img->m_pixels_u16 = malloc(n);
if (img->m_pixels_u16 == NULL && n > 0) {
  Handle_OutOfMemory();
}
```

Comment: Issue is fixed if I use the right specifier. Also, thank you for the other valuable review comments

Answer (score 1):

You mix up height and width:
first with `i = 0`

`j` got to `img->m_width_u32 - 1`
so at the end of the loop you are at
`img->m_pixels_u16 + img->m_width_u32 - 1`

Next loop with `i` set to `one` should be
`img->m_pixels_u16 + img->m_width_u32 + j`

This should be this:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < img->m_height_u32; ++i)
{
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < img->m_width_u32; ++j)
    {
        fscanf(file, "%d", img->m_pixels_u16 + img->m_width_u32 * i + j);
    }
}
```